# Jenkins Pipeline issue :" org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid repository URL"

Tags: jenkins

I am a beginner with Jenkins,
I have configured jenkins which is failing while building UI project, as In my UI project i have absolute path of my plugins which is stored in a specific path in my windows dev environment.e.g: D:/plugins/XXX
Do i need to provide a relative path? is there any script which can help while building UI and resolve this path.
Can anyone help how i can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is already an environment variable in Jenkins that you can use for this purpose.

```
WORKSPACE - The absolute path of the workspace.
```

From 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

Can you modify your build configuration to take an environment variable too?

Comment: No , i don't think i can modify the build configuration to take environment variable. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Never give absolute PATH in any project always provide relative Paths

**Reason**

Your project in your local is and always will be in a specific folder, whereas the project when deploy (Jenkins,Tomcat,...) will be located in a different folder/Different machine altogether :)

Ensure that the JARs/Plugins you need in your project are in your .m2 folder

Just use clean install, it will download all the plugins required into your .m2 folder once and then reuse from there

Unfortunately this is a maven Issue not a Jenkins issue :)

Comment: Hi rohit, So how Jenkins will know about this plugin . what action I am required to do for this. Also can you give some example of relative path.